# hide elements of admin with css file

Tags: admin, admin-css

i use woocommerce and woocommerce Product Vendors (https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/)
i want hide elements of admin with css file "my-admin.css"
I put css file "my-admin.css" at the root of my child theme wordpress
and use this code in functions.php.
This does not work?!?

```
function admin_css() {
    $admin_handle = 'admin_css';
    $admin_stylesheet = get_template_directory_uri() . 'my-admin.css';

    wp_enqueue_style($admin_handle, $admin_stylesheet);
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_css', 11);
```

is this an obselete method?
because:
when i use this other method in functions.php, it's ok it works
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

```
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    body, td, textarea, input, select {
      font-family: "Lucida Grande";
      font-size: 12px;
    } 
  </style>';
}
```

What do you think ?
thanks !!! :)

Comment: here is my corrected code is it better?
because still does not work? here is what my functions.php file contains there may be an error? thank you ! :) <?php /* activation theme */ function wpm_enqueue_styles(){ wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpm_enqueue_styles' ); function wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts() { wp_enqueue_style( 'my-admin-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-admin.css' ); } add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts' );

Comment: I converted your answer into a comment, this isn't a discussion forum and you had not posted a reply, you had posted the solution to your question. People might avoid your question thinking you had found the answer already. If you have updates use the `Edit` link underneath the tags to modify your question to add more information or updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to encapsulate your styles in a separate file, so your first example is closer. That said, the [documentation for admin_print_styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_styles/) says quite clearly:

> admin_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on
> the admin pages. Use admin_enqueue_scripts instead.